# I need to dynamically print out text from a text box. that is loaded from a mysql.

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Here is what I have

```
$(".thoughts_box").blur(function(){
        var box_id= $(this).attr("id").split("_")[$(this).attr("id").split("_").length-1];
        //console.log($(this).attr("id") + " " + $(this).val());
        writeListValue(1,box_id,$(this).val());
    });
<table  width="100%" style="line-height:0px" >
    <tr>
        <td><p>1.</p></td>
        <td><input class="printArea_1 thoughts_box" name="activities_thoughts_1" id="activities_thoughts_1" type="text" style="width:345px;" placeholder="Type or click list button &gt;" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="thoughts_1"  class="list_btn ext_thoughts" value="List &gt;" name="_1" /></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Delegate the event.**

Instead of

```
$(".thoughts_box").blur(function()
```

try

```
$(document).on("blur", ".thoughts_box", function()
```

or better

```
$('table').on("blur", ".thoughts_box", function()
```